# Simulate Sending an SMS to the iPhone Simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sms

Is there a way in xcode to simulate sending an sms to the iPhone simulator?

I don't need to actually send a real SMS. I just need to look at how the message body displays in a bunch of different versions of iOS.

I know Android Studio allows you to do this very easily, and I was wondering if there was a similar solution for iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

There is also no SMS application (Message app) installed in the simulator.

If you just need some notification displayed in your simulator, you can try to schedule a local notification from your app that is running under that simulator. You can find many tutorial online, like this: 
https://medium.com/@dkw5877/local-notifications-in-ios-156a03b81ceb

Answer (score -1):

you can.
At least in iOS 11.4 and higher versions. The Messages app has two contacts, and they are linked in a loopback fashion - sending a message as Kate will arrive in the John contact, and vice versa.

1. open simulator.
2. open messages App
   [image]
3. select one of two contacts in it
   [image]
4. send them sms though the simulator UI
   [image]

Comment: you cannot send SMS (text messages) or receive SMS or iMessage on the simulator

Comment: but... but the question asked about receiving an sms, not sending